# Linux not scheduling waiting tasks on idle CPU

Tags: linux, cpu, scheduler, scheduling, perf

I'm running an up-to-date Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS.
The Linux 4.4 kernel frequently refuses to schedule my worker threads, even though there is an idle core.

I've captured the suspect scheduling with:

```
$ perf sched record sleep 0.1
$ perf timechart
```

[image: timechart]

It clearly shows that CPU0 and CPU1 are idle for several milliseconds while the tasks blox:5425,5426,5427,5428 show up in yellow as waiting for a CPU.

Surely, CPU Cores should not be kept idle if there processes/threads waiting to run?

Am I being affected by Linux scheduler bugs [described here](https://blog.acolyer.org/2016/04/26/the-linux-scheduler-a-decade-of-wasted-cores/)?

I'm pretty sure I didn't always have this issue, it just started happening at some point.

Why is this happening, and are there any facilities in Ubuntu that lets me tweak the behaviour of the task scheduler. Maybe via some sysctl command? Or would trying a different scheduling strategy require a custom compiled kernel?

**OS:** Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS
**Kernel:** Linux ubuntu64 4.4.0-98-generic
**CPU:** Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4570 CPU @ 3.20GHz

Comment: That's really tough to tell from just a screenshot. Please help us reproduce the issue and provide raw observations, e.g. `perf.data`. Thread affinity is also important to know - and might help you in this case.

Comment: Voting to close : "Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a **clear problem statement* are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example]https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" . May also be more appropriate on https://unix.stackexchange.com . Good luck.